# how to get a text which is starting with 1-3 and having 4 digits after that and Then space and E and 6 digits in .net using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

regex [1-3][0-9]{4}(?: E[0-9]{6})?$

```
sample data
    successful my registration id is #12345 E112233 (should match)
    Successful my data is #22331 E001122          (should match)
    failing    12345                             (should not match)
```

Expected OP

```
12345 E112233

22331 E001122
```

code -

```
var content ="successful my registration id is #12345 E112233
Successful my data is #22331 E001122          
failing    12345";

       var regex = new Regex(@"[1-3]\d{4}([ ]E\d{6})?$",RegexOptions.Multiline);
       var REG_ID = regex.Match(myStringData).Value;
```

Comment: Do you want to match only after `#`? Then add it, `#[1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?$`. Or do you want to match the entire string? Then use `^[1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?$` (and remove `RegexOptions.Multilin`)

Comment: i want to match and get the word after the #. getting result with #,

Comment: Ok, so you need `var REG_ID = Regex.Match(myStringData, @"#([1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?)$")?.Groups[1].Value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var REG_ID = Regex.Match(myStringData, @"#([1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?)$")?.Groups[1].Value;
// OR - if you use a lookbehind
var REG_ID = Regex.Match(myStringData, @"(?<=#)[1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?$")?.Value;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD4XIr/1).

**Pattern details**

- `#` - find `#` first (`(?<=#)` finds a location that is immediately preceded with a `#` char)
- `([1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?)` - then capture (into Group 1):

  - `[1-3]\d{4}` - a `1`/`2`/`3` digit + four digits
  - `(?: E\d{6})?` - an optional sequence of a space + `E` + six digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: cant we get the data without # with the Match Property, instead of using group?

Comment: @krishnamohan Ok, you can use a lookbehind based pattern, but these are synonyms.

Comment: can we have 1 space or no space before E, some code like [ ]E{0,1}, failed - #12345E112233 (it should match)

Comment: (?<=#)[1-3]\d{4}(?: {0,1}E\d{6})?$
this worked for me

Comment: @krishnamohan Use `(?<=#)[1-3]\d{4}(?: ?E\d{6})?$`